# run link.exe on libraries

Tags: visual-c++, linker

Here is the case where I run link.exe on libraries to create an executable; but the executable does not work.

```
file1.cpp is compiled to file1.obj;
file2.cpp is compiled to file2.obj;
file3.cpp is compiled to file3.obj which includes the function of main;

file1.obj is lib-ed into file1.lib;
file2.obj is lib-ed into file2.lib;
file3.obj is lib-ed into file3.lib;
```

Here is the command line used to link file1.lib, file2.lib and file3.lib into test.exe:

```
"link.exe file3.lib file2.lib file1.lib /nologo /OUT:test.exe /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE libcmt.lib"
```

when I run ./test.exe, it returns 1 which means it crashed somewhere;
while when I run the following command line:

```
"link.exe file3.obj file2.lib file1.lib /nologo /OUT:test.exe /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE libcmt.lib"
```

everything is fine and ./test.exe runs well.

May I ask your help to let me know the difference btw the above two commend lines internally?
Thanks.
Damon

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, why are you not letting it do the work for you with creating libraries and linking?

Comment: Cygwin is used as the platform in Windows where compilers and linkers are called in the makefiles;
Please note that it is a test case which should be used for all platform. So in Linux and Mac, the same test case should be used; just change the options, compilers and linkers.

Comment: If you are using cygwin as your compiler/linker, then how does the visual-c++ tag make any sense?

Comment: I am not using cygwin as my compiler/linker; I am using cygwin as the platform, where msvc compiler/linker (cl.exe, link.exe and lib.exe) are used as the toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running different code because your .obj modules aren't used.

Check your map file. The `.obj` modules from a library are copied only if there is at least on external that it resolves. `.obj` files specified at the command line are always linked.